# How to proper configure "Go Build" and what are the differences between Run Kind

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

I am new to Go language and also to the IDE GoLand so I am sorry if this is very basic.

I am currently trying to configure Run Kind for package for all my files, the problem is I cannot seem to get the configuration straight, I get this error:

> "can't load package: package Course: unknown import path "Course": cannot find module providing package Course"

My GOROOT is the standard in `C:` and GOPATH is in my directory of workplace with the folders: `scr`, `bin` and `pkg`. Inside `scr` is course folder with training files for Go.

I have tried to google every option on how to properly configure the go Build configuration, I might be missing to install packages not sure to be honest, I have installed the gotools and everything from golang.org, and tried following the guide from GoLand in JetBrains but no luck in properly configuring package, or Dir options.

I can create a go Build for each file using Run Kind: File, but I want to create one for all the files inside the folder not one each time I want to run one.

Also I have no idea what `-i` in Go tool arguments means.

Comment: Joe, do you have a main func declared in your code? Or even a main package declared as well? Can you share some code for us to see what's going on?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67573905/1663774 for an answer about the `-i` argument

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need to do is simply enable go module integration. Find the setting at `File | Settings | Go | Go Modules (vgo)`. In that panel also make sure `Vgo executable` is set to your Project SDK. If it's still not working, enabling the vendor experiment option at `File | Settings | Go | Build Tags & Vendoring` may help. Be sure your project specific settings aren't overriding these values as well.