# What is the `-i` option for "Go tool arguments" in GoLand's Run/Debug Configurations window?

Tags: go, goland

What is the  `-i` option for "Go tool arguments" in GoLand's Run/Debug Configurations window?[image]

Answer (score 7):

Taken from `go help build`:

```
The -i flag installs the packages that are dependencies of the target.
The -i flag is deprecated. Compiled packages are cached automatically.
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a message while uses it:

> go build: -i flag is deprecated

**The -i build flag**

> The -i flag accepted by go build, go install, and go test is now
> deprecated. The -i flag instructs the go command to install packages
> imported by packages named on the command line. Since the build cache
> was introduced in Go 1.10, the -i flag no longer has a significant
> effect on build times, and it causes errors when the install directory
> is not writable.

It is from [Go 1.16 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command)

So its presence doesn't matter now and you can remove this flag from arguments